# Getting start and end of selected text from tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-3

I have configured the `tinyMCE` editor with a custom context menu. When I right-click on any word in the editor, the chosen word gets highlighted. I am able to get the selected text with `editor.selection.getContent()`.

1. How do I get the start and end points of the selected text within the entire text that is currently in the tinyMCE editor? I tried `editor.selection.getStart()` and `getEnd()`, but that has not yielded enough results.

My task is to take the start and end indices and get the previous word with it. I am currently using `tinymce-3.5.10`.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use

```
var range = editor.selection.getRng()
```

to get a range. You can get the start- and end-container using

```
range.startContainer
range.endContainer
```

Comment: I used that like so:   `var range = editor.selection.getRng(true);
    console.log("Range = " + range);
    console.log("text = " + range.startContainer.textContent);`
I get the selected text, but how do I get the start and end indices? The startContainer and endContainer return an object of type Element.

Comment: then you use range.endOffset and range.startOffset

Comment: Thanks. That works, but only as long as the text is not within any tags. `startOffset` and `endOffset` give (I think) position between a tag. So if I choose the text "test" within the sentence: This is a good <u>test</u>. I will get 0 and 4 as output of start and end offset. So then, my only alternative is to strip the text of any tags and try again?

Comment: you might be able to get the desired behaviour if you could trigger a double click on the word that has been right cicked. the default browser behaviour is to select the word autatically then. If this doesn't work for you you will have to strip the tags and look for wordboundaries which is a more complicated, then reset the range accordingly and you are done.