# Tinymce get start and end index of selection taking html characters into account

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, editor, selection

I am actually trying to find a way to gather the start and end indexes of the selection object of tinymce. The reason why I want that is that i want to take the selection when a button is clicked, modify it and then render it back exactly where I had taken it.

Indeed, I have already seen `tinymce.activeEditor.getRng().startOffset` and `tinymce.activeEditor.getRng().endOffset` but it gives the index of the text so if there is an html tag, it fails (ex: if the content is `<h2>Test</h2>` and I select the first T, I will get 0 and not 4).

Does someone know a way to achieve ?
Cause I have searched a lot but did not find a single viable solution, and really need it to be able to add texte at a specific place after modifications with socket IO !

Thanks in advance !
Regards

I have looked at [Getting start and end of selected text from tinyMCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507165/getting-start-and-end-of-selected-text-from-tinymce) but there was no real solution too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.